# Giving string name to the texts in the code

Tags: java, android

I want to give string name instead of text like "**just now**" "**a minute ago**" here but it doesn't accept I used **getString** or **R.string** it didn't work

```
final long diff = now - time;
    if (diff < MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return "just now";
    } else if (diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return "a minute ago";
    } else if (diff < 50 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return diff / MINUTE_MILLIS + " minutes ago";
    } else if (diff < 90 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return "an hour ago";
    } else if (diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
        return diff / HOUR_MILLIS + " hours ago";
    } else if (diff < 48 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
        return "yesterday";
    } else {
        return diff / DAY_MILLIS + " days ago";
    }
```

What i want to do

```
final long diff = now - time;
    if (diff < MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return getString(R.string.lbl_just_now);
    } else if (diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return getString(R.string.lbl_a_minute_ago);
    } else if (diff < 50 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return diff / MINUTE_MILLIS + getString(R.string.lbl_minutes_ago);
    } else if (diff < 90 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return getString(R.string.lbl_an_hour_ago);
    } else if (diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
        return diff / HOUR_MILLIS + getString(R.string.lbl_hours_ago);
    } else if (diff < 48 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
        return getString(R.string.lbl_yesterday);
    } else {
        return diff / DAY_MILLIS + getString(R.string.lbl_days_ago);
    }
```

Comment: What error you are getting when using  getString(..) ? And Where you are trying to access the getString() ? For  your  Information  getString() can we used  with a context only like in  Activity/Fragment

Comment: In which class is the code located in?

Comment: Please refer to this link to improve your resource string design https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource

Answer (score 1):

`getString` [is a method on a `Context` object](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getString(int,%20java.lang.Object...)), so you can't just call it from anywhere. It works inside an `Activity` because that *is* a `Context`. And it works inside a `Fragment` because that class has its own `getString` method, and the framework provides it with a `Context` object it uses to get the string.

Depending on where your code is, you might have access to a `Context` - `View`s have a `getContext` method, for example. But if you don't already have access to one wherever that code is (e.g. inside your own custom class), you'll need to *pass* a `Context` in. This is pretty typical in Android, lots of functions and constructors take a `context` parameter.

So in that case, you'll have to do something like this:

```
public String getLabelOrWhatever(Context context, long time) {
    final long diff = now - time;
    if (diff < MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return context.getString(R.string.lbl_just_now);
    } else if (diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return context.getString(R.string.lbl_a_minute_ago);
    }
    // etc.
}
```

Also you should probably be using [format strings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#formatting-strings), like this:

```
<string name="lbl_hours_ago">%1$d hours ago</string>
```

That's argument *1*, which is a *decimal* (integer) value. (There's also `$f` for floating-point numbers, and $s for strings.) Then you can pass the values to insert into your `getString` call

```
context.getString(R.string.lbl_hours_ago, diff / HOUR_MILLIS)
```

and it'll be inserted in the right place. (You might want to look at [plural strings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#Plurals) too - they can pull out the correct string depending on the value, e.g. *hour* vs *hours* in English.)

Comment: I left the whole code below, I tried the code you gave, it gave an error

Comment: @Emre Which error?  This code should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.whatsup;

import android.app.Application;

public class GetTimeAgo extends Application {

    private static final int SECOND_MILLIS = 1000;
    private static final int MINUTE_MILLIS = 60 * SECOND_MILLIS;
    private static final int HOUR_MILLIS = 60 * MINUTE_MILLIS;
    private static final int DAY_MILLIS = 24 * HOUR_MILLIS;


    public static String getTimeAgo(long time) {
        if (time < 1000000000000L) {
            // if timestamp given in seconds, convert to millis
            time *= 1000;
        }

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (time > now || time <= 0) {
            return null;
        }

        final long diff = now - time;
        if (diff < MINUTE_MILLIS) {
            return "just now";
        } else if (diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
            return "a minute ago";
        } else if (diff < 50 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
            return diff / MINUTE_MILLIS + " minutes ago";
        } else if (diff < 90 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
            return "an hour ago";
        } else if (diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
            return diff / HOUR_MILLIS + " hours ago";
        } else if (diff < 48 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
            return "yesterday";
        } else {
            return diff / DAY_MILLIS + " days ago";
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [cactustictacs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13598222/cactustictacs) is perfect, however, I would like to clear up why your code is not working.

You try to call `getName()` in a `static` method inside of your `Application`. static members (methods, fields) can be called from anywhere, without having a reference to the `Application` (`this`). Thus, you need to remove `static` from `getTimeAgo`.

However, you cannot call it from anywhere anymore. You'll have to have an object of `GetTimeAgo`, e.g:

```
GetTimeAgo application= ...;
application.getTimeAgo(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

or call it from within a non-`static` method of `GetTimeAgo` itself.

p.s:

When your class is really only calculating something, it doesn't need to extend Application at all, but take a `Context` as a parameter.